# Check string contain math operation valid or not?

Tags: mysql, sql, math, expression

I have a table for formula grade where the user can create their own formula using the operator, column, dan number, which I have provided on app UI

| formulaid | tipe | formula | gradecatid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | operator | ( | NULL |
| 1 | column | PAS | 5 |
| 1 | operator | + | NULL |
| 1 | column | PTS | 4 |
| 1 | operator | ) | NULL |
| 1 | operator | / | NULL |
| 1 | number | 2 | NULL |

the math string is from formula column, column type is another value from another grade type

```
( PAS + PTS ) / 2
```

last process will become string

```
( Number + Number ) / 2
```

Note:
This formula only the sample, the formula can be in any form for other example `( 5+1+2+3) / 4`, or `1 + 1`, it's not fix to this form `( Number + Number ) / 2`,  the user can create any formula with the given functionality as mention above, operator, number, and column.

Is it possible to evaluate this string in mysql to determine is valid math operation or not?

Comment: Answer: probably not; you would need an expression parser/compiler to do this.

Comment: I don't see anything in your sample data that shows what order the formula rows are in?

Comment: Explain more about the Number being substituted.  Where do the numbers come from?  What do pas/pts mean and are there others like that?

Comment: the order is directly from top to bottom, but I can added another column for id increment

Comment: PAS or PTS is another type of grade, it using gradecatid as key to connect to other table that contain grade number type

Comment: You can build the query  kind of `select  (pas.col5+pts.col4)/2 from .. limit 1` or whatever the formula means and run the query to get ok or err .

Comment: Good idea @Serg, i will try using select first, to test the math expression

Comment: In SQL, tables are inherently *unordered* bags of rows. There's no "top to bottom" if there isn't one or more columns *in* the data that can be used to define an ordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I create this SP based on @Serg suggestion I try to create below SP for handling the error

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_TEST()
BEGIN
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN 
SHOW ERRORS; 
END;      
SET @sql = 'SELECT ( 100 + 100  / 2';
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
END;
CALL SP_TEST();
```

it will show error if there's any bad math operation

Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

You use this code via regex [mysql]

```sql
SELECT '(5+9)/2' REGEXP '\\(([0-9]+)\\+([0-9]+)\\)\\/2';
```

> can change '(5+9)/2' to input value

[image: code example in w3schools mysql compiler]

| operator | regex code |
| --- | --- |
| + | `\\+` |
| * | `\\/` |
| / | `\\*` |
| - | `\\-` |
| ( | `\\(` |
| ) | `\\)` |
| int number | `([0-9]+)` |
| float number | `([0-9]+|[.|][0-9]+)` |

> it's so hard )

Comment: thank you for your answer, but the formula will be very random, there's no fix like this form `(5+9)/2`, it can be any form `( 5+1+2+3) / 4`, or `1 + 1`

Comment: @bagi2info.com You have a schedule to prepare the formula dynamically.
In this way, prepare the regex code dynamically.
my answer has a table showing what to replace with what
Use this table

Comment: @bagi2info.com It will be easier for you if you remove the spaces

Comment: no, it's too much process if using schedule and like I said it's has random form

Comment: @bagi2info.com You open a new column and write the regex code in it. I don't think there will be any problem in performance.